# Scroll and run a code when section is visible ( pure Javascript )

Tags: javascript

```js
 function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}
animateValue("num1", 0, 75, 10000);

var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;

if(scrollTop > 400){
 animateValue("num2", 0, 75, 10000);
}
```

```css
.box{
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="num1">75</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
<h1 id="num2">75</h1>
```

I need to run the number from 0 to 75 on id="num2", like id="num1" is working. But I need id="num2" running after page is scrolled down there. And its a challenge because I can't use any library like Jquery, angular JS etc. I need it using **pure JavaScript**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some events for scrolling and resizing (both can "show" the target element). We don't need the scrolling position when using `.getBoundingClientRect()`, because it shows us the targets `top` position depending on the scroll position.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/q8ww67tj/
```

```js
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
 var range = end - start;
 var current = start;
 var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
 var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
 var obj = document.getElementById(id);
 var timer = setInterval(function() {
  current += increment;
  obj.innerHTML = current;
  if (current == end) {
   clearInterval(timer);
  }
 }, stepTime);
}
animateValue("num1", 0, 75, 10000);

triggered = false;
window.addEventListener('load', recalculate);
window.addEventListener('scroll', recalculate);
window.addEventListener('resize', recalculate);

function recalculate() {
 var height = document.body.clientHeight,
  targetRect = document.getElementById('num2').getBoundingClientRect();
  targetY = targetRect['top'],
  targetHeight = targetRect['height'];
 
 if (targetY + targetHeight < height) {
  if (!triggered) {
   triggered = true;
   animateValue("num2", 0, 75, 10000);
  }
 }
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="num1">75</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
<h1 id="num2">75</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now. And noticed that whole event have to be on window.onload function. Thank you again. :D

Comment: If you're using vanilla (pure) JS, you should add events with window.addEventListener (like my code above) instead of on('load') to prevent collisions and override. I added a load event, too (the first events of the three).